# How to call messages.property (parametrized) value from javascript on a gsp page

Tags: javascript, grails, internationalization

I am new in grails and trying to set value from messages.property (i18n) in g:set tag on gsp and then use it in java script on the same gsp page. For example:

my messages.property should look like:
**operation.hello=Hello '{0}'**

in the gsp there should be:

```
<g:set var="foo" value="${operation.hello('Patty')}" scope="page"/>
```

and

```
<g:javascript>
  alert( $foo )
</g:javascript>
```

not sure how to handle this.Can anyone help?

**our basic intention is to use a parametrized-messages.property value from javascript.**

Tried JAWR plug-in and that worked well but JAWR had other issues that we do not want in our case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you understand that all this is pocessed on the server side, I think all you need to do is use the correct syntax:

```
<g:set var="foo" value="${g.message(code: 'operation.hello', args: ['Patty'])}" scope="page"/>

<g:javascript>
  alert( "${foo}" );
</g:javascript>
```

By the time this reaches the browser, it should simply read:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert( "Hello Patty" );
</script>
```

Comment: That's good. But how to call a message property in g:set tag?

Comment: Are you saying the code you wrote to set the foo variable does not work?

Comment: To be safe you should use `${foo.encodeAsJavaScript()}` to escape things like double and single quotes in the message.

Comment: **Thank you so much for your help. I am almost there following Gregg's example but the parameter is not working and I am seeing alert as "Hello '{0}' . Any suggestion?**

Comment: Gregg's ans worked perfectly with a little change in my **message.property file** :  messages.property should look like: **operation.hello=Hello ''{0}''**  _italic_ ** ( two single quote instead of one) ** _italic_

Answer (score 1):

If I got what you mean, basically you can't.

G tags are server side stuff. Their value args must be present while the g tags are rendered, you cannot pass a javascript (client side) value to g tag (which basically it's a server side snippet). You can put the result of a g tag into a javascript string, not the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var helloTo = "Patty";
     var message = "${g.message(code: 'operation.hello', args: ["+ helloTo + "])}";
</script>
```